# Extend language list in Android browser

Tags: android, cordova, chromium

I need to support a lesser known language in my cordova application ( [Tok Pisin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tok_Pisin) ). It looks like iOS will support it as a secondary language -- that is, the UI isn't localized for the iPhone / iPad, but it'll send down tpi as the preferred language, so that we can provide Tok Pisin strings in our app.

But I don't see Tok Pisin in the list of languages for either Chrome or Android. Is there any way to customize the list of preferred languages -- to add Tok Pisin to the list -- such that my app can pick up the setting and provide the correct strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to add to the languages list, but there *is* a way to set the language and region to something not on the list.

There are a set of apps in the Google Play store that will allow you to set your region / language to something more exotic, even if the language is not on your list: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=locale&c=apps&hl=en.

In my case, I installed "MoreLocale 2" based off a few recommendations from Android support forums. Setting the locale didn't work right away either; I needed to connect my tablet in USB debugging mode and explicitly give the app permission to change the configuration:

`adb shell pm grant jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`

And then it allowed me to change the locale to Tok Pisin (tpi).